# Make a difficult page editable

Tags: customization

There's this page http://voitair.com/scent-system/scent-system I need to make editable via admin panel. It has to be understandable for a non-programmer. What system or plugin or anything can I use to make it still function as now but be editable?

Comment: What kind of edit you want? Do you want to allow edit the text or design ?

Comment: Just the content - text, images, add more slides (content that slides when arrows are clicked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a combination of two techniques will get you all the way there.

### 1. Shortcodes

It's really easy to use shortcodes to wrap various content in a `<div>`/`<span>`/`<section>`. Take a look at the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). Then you could take something like this:

```
[tabs]
    [tab title="Tab 1"]The tab #1 content[/tab]
    [tab title="Another Tab"]The tab #2 content[/tab]
[tabs]
```

And output it as:

```
<article class="tabs">
    <section class="tab">
        <h3>Tab 1</h3>
        <div class="tab-content">The tab #1 content.</div>
    </section>
    <section class="tab">
        <h3>Another Tab</h3>
        <div class="tab-content">The tab #2 content.</div>
    </section>
</article>
```

There are a lot of plugins that do this like shortcodes ultimate, but I think they tend to be rather bloated. I'd code tihs myself if it were me.

### 2. Custom Post Type & Taxonomy

Using shortcodes, you could extend the above patterns one step further and also have a `[slide]` shortcode, but I think that might start getting too convoluted.

At this point, I think it makes sense to have a "slide" custom post type and then use a "slideshow" custom taxonomy to sort each slide into one or more slideshows. You could enable the menu order field to control the slide order to set that up as a custom meta box.

I see that you're using AnythingSlider which has a WordPress plugin that works similarly. It's possible even that you could combine that and shortcodes ultimate to get this working with now extra work, but I can't promise that will work.

### The result

In the end, your solution's workflow would go like this:

1. Create a "Slide" post.
2. Use the shortcodes to define the tabs in each slide.
3. Assign the slide to a slideshow taxonomy term.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 for all the remaining slides.

Then, it's up to you to put together a template that queries the slideshow and outputs all the code you need. Alternately, maybe you make a final shortcode that places it for you like this: `[slideshow cat="My first slideshow" /]`

Comment: Thanks, I made it with Shortcodes, though it's not very user-friendly for regular people. But I guess I need much more experience to make a wysiwig editor for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a custom theme settings page which can be used to get content or other settings from users. There is [nice article](http://themeshaper.com/2010/06/03/sample-theme-options/) on *( ThemeShaper.com )* describing same.

#### Other useful Resources -

- Custom settings page - [Using The Settings API](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-settings-api-part-1-create-a-theme-options-page/)
- [Creating a custom WordPress theme options page](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/02/creating-a-custom-wordpress-theme-options-page/)